# Azure Permissions to get information on a resource without being able to read it

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am working on an Azure application that gets the resources in a subscription, and then gets some information on them, e.g. get all the storage resources then get all the properties for them.

```
    storage_client = StorageManagementClient(
        session.client_secret_credentials,
        session.subscription_id,
        api_version="2021-06-01",
    )

    storage_account: StorageAccount = storage_client.storage_accounts.get_properties(
        resource_group,
        storage_account_id,
    )
```

I want the app to have the minimum permissions so that it can only get the existence and information about the resource but not read the contents of the resource at all.
The application does a similar thing in AWS where it uses the security audit role.

Is there are role in Azure that can do this? If not is it possible to create one? All the MS documentation I have looked at just talks about Read permissions which does not seem what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Reader permission on a Storage account does not allow you access to the contents of the Storage account.
There are separate roles/permissions for data access.
Of course there are also access keys but to get them the app would need Write permissions to the Storage account.

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal#assign-an-azure-role

> The Reader role is an Azure Resource Manager role that permits users
> to view storage account resources, but not modify them. It does not
> provide read permissions to data in Azure Storage, but only to account
> management resources.